# Edit all records by ID (Swift 4, CoreData)

Tags: swift, core-data

I have **Int** array with values

**Example:**

var SelectedCard = [Int] ()

[3, 1, 2]

---

Me need edit my all records by **order**

Im tried this but app crash

[image]

```
for item in 0...SelectedCard.count-1 {
        let order = SelectedCard[item]

        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Card")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "order == %@", order)

        do {
            if let fetchResults = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Card] {
                if fetchResults.count != 0 {
                    for index in 0...fetchResults.count-1 {
                        let managedObject = fetchResults[index]
                        managedObject.setValue("", forKey: "folderID")
                    }
                    appDelegate.saveContext()
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
}
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the predicate to

```
NSPredicate(format: "order == \(order)")
```